# How do I install the lodown library from GitHub?

Tags: r, github

I need to install a package available on GitHub, but I simply can't install it following the recommended steps provided from the developer. The package is `lodown` (https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown) and my R version is 3.5.2. RStudio is 1.1.463.

I've tried the standard method using `install_github()` function. The guide is the following: http://asdfree.com/prerequisites.html.

The R asks me which package I want to update, and the `lodown` isn't among them.

```
install.packages("devtools" , repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library(devtools)
install_github("ajdamico/lodown" , dependencies = TRUE)
```

The method should be working, but it is failing at the third line, in the function `install_github()`.

```
> install_github( "ajdamico/lodown" , dependencies = TRUE )
Downloading GitHub repo ajdamico/lodown@master
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

 1:   All                                         2:   CRAN packages only                          3:   None                                     
 4:   ellipsis (0.1.0     -> 0.2.0     ) [CRAN]   5:   evaluate (0.13      -> 0.14      ) [CRAN]   6:   ggplot2  (3.1.1     -> 3.2.0     ) [CRAN]
 7:   mime     (0.6       -> 0.7       ) [CRAN]   8:   numDeriv (2016.8-1  -> 2016.8-1.1) [CRAN]   9:   openssl  (1.3       -> 1.4       ) [CRAN]
10:   progress (1.2.0     -> 1.2.2     ) [CRAN]  11:   purrr    (0.3.0     -> 0.3.2     ) [CRAN]  12:   R6       (2.3.0     -> 2.4.0     ) [CRAN]
13:   Rcpp     (1.0.0     -> 1.0.1     ) [CRAN]  14:   RCurl    (1.95-4.11 -> 1.95-4.12 ) [CRAN]  15:   readxl   (1.2.0     -> 1.3.1     ) [CRAN]
16:   rlang    (0.3.1     -> 0.3.4     ) [CRAN]  17:   survey   (3.35-1    -> 3.36      ) [CRAN]  18:   sys      (3.1       -> 3.2       ) [CRAN]
19:   tibble   (2.0.1     -> 2.1.3     ) [CRAN]  
Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1: 
Installing 38 packages: digest, gridExtra, gtable, haven, highr, Hmisc, htmlTable, htmltools, htmlwidgets, jpeg, knitr, labeling, latticeExtra, lazyeval, markdown, memisc, mitools, munsell, plyr, R.methodsS3, R.oo, R.utils, RColorBrewer, read.dbc, repr, reshape2, rvest, SAScii, scales, selectr, vctrs, viridis, viridisLite, xfun, XML, xml2, xtable, zeallot
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/Rik/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/digest_0.6.19.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 210882 bytes (205 KB)
downloaded 205 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gridExtra_2.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1108369 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gtable_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 433009 bytes (422 KB)
downloaded 422 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/haven_2.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1022173 bytes (998 KB)
downloaded 998 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/highr_0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 48197 bytes (47 KB)
downloaded 47 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/Hmisc_4.2-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3091465 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/htmlTable_1.13.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 333662 bytes (325 KB)
downloaded 325 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/htmltools_0.3.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 660933 bytes (645 KB)
downloaded 645 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/htmlwidgets_1.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 805008 bytes (786 KB)
downloaded 786 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/jpeg_0.1-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 230449 bytes (225 KB)
downloaded 225 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/knitr_1.23.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1417400 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/labeling_0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 61756 bytes (60 KB)
downloaded 60 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/latticeExtra_0.6-28.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2192165 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/lazyeval_0.2.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 170834 bytes (166 KB)
downloaded 166 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/markdown_1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 189484 bytes (185 KB)
downloaded 185 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/memisc_0.99.17.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2443694 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/mitools_2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 297982 bytes (290 KB)
downloaded 290 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/munsell_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 243683 bytes (237 KB)
downloaded 237 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/plyr_1.8.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1295899 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/R.methodsS3_1.7.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 76526 bytes (74 KB)
downloaded 74 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/R.oo_1.22.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 957248 bytes (934 KB)
downloaded 934 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/R.utils_2.9.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1377504 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 55498 bytes (54 KB)
downloaded 54 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/read.dbc_1.0.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 42590 bytes (41 KB)
downloaded 41 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/repr_1.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 119260 bytes (116 KB)
downloaded 116 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/reshape2_1.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 627060 bytes (612 KB)
downloaded 612 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rvest_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 914445 bytes (893 KB)
downloaded 893 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/SAScii_1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 43655 bytes (42 KB)
downloaded 42 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/scales_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1065105 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/selectr_0.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 490610 bytes (479 KB)
downloaded 479 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vctrs_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 617579 bytes (603 KB)
downloaded 603 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/viridis_0.5.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1866693 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/viridisLite_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 60481 bytes (59 KB)
downloaded 59 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xfun_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 171553 bytes (167 KB)
downloaded 167 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/XML_3.98-1.20.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4601568 bytes (4.4 MB)
downloaded 4.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xml2_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3614997 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xtable_1.8-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 704723 bytes (688 KB)
downloaded 688 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/zeallot_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 61412 bytes (59 KB)
downloaded 59 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’
> library(lodown)
Error in library(lodown) : there is no package called ‘lodown’
```

Comment: What is the error? What OS are you on? If on windows, do you have RTools installed?

Comment: When it fails, what error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: Yes, I have the RTools installed.

Comment: There is no error message, the R just asks me which package I want to update and in the end, the "library(lodown)" command doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated the post with the output.

Comment: Have you tried in a fresh R session? The problem seems to be with "Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’". So maybe it can't update the package because you are currently using it? Maybe try updating `digest` before running the `devtools` stuff? I'm surprised that so many packages need updating. Seems like your library folder might just be out of date in general.

Comment: Please put linked-text like that in your question, in order to keep in reproducible and meaningful. If/when the external link goes stale, the body of the question will be inadequate to convey the full situation. From pastebin's [FAQ](https://pastebin.com/faq#18), they can easily expire. I suggest you put all of that logging output in a [generic code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), where SO's normal behavior is to show *so-many-lines* and make you scroll through the rest ... so your question does not appear as long as this comment ;-) (I've suggested an edit to this end.)

Comment: I think it might be the case. After the update, other packages like 'Rcpp' showed the same error. I repeated the procedure and it worked at the end. Thanks for the attention.